# How to setup aws lambda on existing spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, deployment, aws-lambda

I want to configure aws lambda in my existing Spring boot project. In my project i am using lombok, kafka consumer, and microservice. I follow steps at:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot

I added dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
        <version>[0.1,)</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have some issues with this steps:

1. Do i need to remove `@ComponentScan` and use `@Import`  for all classes. Means if i have 10 controllers and 4 service classes and 2 repository classes that we are autowiring, So do we need to add all these classes in `@Import`

Actually i am new in this. Can anyone help me with simple steps?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to deploy your entire Spring Boot application to AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda will still work with `@ComponentScan` but the **cold-start** will take longer because of the all classes scan, which is mentioned in the tutorial. You can read more about cold-start in java, for example here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/java-apis-aws-lambda (see "Cold start notes"). In short, when AWS Lambda doesn't reuse a container with your function/application it starts the application and scans all the classes while executing `@ComponentScan`. With `@Import` you avoid this scan, and that makes cold-start faster.

You can also check the code sample for this package https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/tree/master/samples/springboot/pet-store

Comment: Do we need to put `Outputs.SpringBootPetStoreApi.Value` in sam.yml file?. sam.yaml file is important?

Comment: In my application i have no API but have kafka consumer.

Comment: If we have multiple controller, we have to put `@EnableWebMvc` in all controller?

Comment: Can you please provide me sample code having mulliple controller with service and repository?

Comment: You don't need `Outputs` section in case you don't plan to reuse any resources from this template in the others. 
As you have a Kafka consumer, then you probably would like to pass the connection configuration through environment parameters to the lambda. Check this doc for reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html and use in the Lambda definition like `Environment: Variables: ENV_VAR_NAME: "value"` (or you can start with a hardcoded value).

Comment: You don't need to add `EnableWebMvc` if you don't use it. Consider the application has the same structure, the `aws-serverless-java-container-spring` package only replaces the server code, all the controllers and other business logic will be the same.

Comment: Ok It really help me